# frame.destroy() and frame.quit() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I  am using python 3 I want to close an tkinter window to continue in code, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def window():
    global frame
    frame = Tk()

    Button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="No.", command=frame.quit)
    Button1.pack(anchor=S, fill=X, side=RIGHT)
    Button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Yes!", fg="dark green", command=func)
    Button2.pack(anchor=S, fill=X, side=LEFT)
    frame.mainloop()
 def func():
    frame.destroy()
    frame.quit()
    messagebox.showinfo("Help", "Please help me.")
    #Next step ....

window()
```

I want to exit the script with Button1 and continue and close the window with Button2, but I can't close the window in use of an other function.

Comment: FYI, if you import * from tkinter, there is no need to then import messagebox. In fact, you should be able to compile using just the first import line

Comment: I recommend not importing tkinter twice

Comment: @WalleCyril Technically all python will do is just set a reference to the previously imported library and not actually import it twice. But I agree, bad practice.

Comment: Can you provide what error message you are receiving OP?

Comment: The code run, but I can` close the window with frame.destroy() in func().

Comment: There is no error massage, but the first window does not close.

Comment: *does not close, if I press Button2.

Comment: Seems to be working here after fixing the indentation error. I press Button2, the windows disappear and the message box is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it,
the problem was: Evry messagebox need an main window, I have destroyed this main window before starting the massagebox and the messagebox started an new emty main window. My resulution is to minimize the main window, start the messagebox and after that to close the massagebox for cotinueing in code.

```
 from tkinter import *

 from tkinter import messagebox

main = Tk()
main.geometry("500x400+300+300")
def message():
  main.geometry("0x0")
  messagebox.showwarning("Say Hello", "Hello World")
  main.destroy()
B1 = Button(main, text = "Start Dialog",fg="dark green", command = message)
B1.pack()

main.mainloop()

print("finish dialog")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def window():
    global frame
    frame = tk.Tk()

    Button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="No.", command=func)
    Button1.pack(anchor=tk.S, fill=tk.X, side=tk.RIGHT)
    Button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Yes!", fg="dark green", command=func)
    Button2.pack(anchor=tk.S, fill=tk.X, side=tk.LEFT)
    frame.mainloop()
def func():
    global frame
    frame.destroy()
    messagebox.showinfo("Help", "Please help me.")
    #Next step ....

window()
```

Comment: Nothing chaned: The Window doesn`t close only the text and the buttons leave.